# How to loop over and track all form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to keep track of all form fields so that I can do different tasks e.g. validation, animation, etc. Currently I have the code written out in long form which repeats itself quite a bit. How can I get each `text` or `textarea` or `email` input from an HTML form and track it, while being able to update it's associated label?

Current code which works but is redundant:

```
<script>
    $username = $('#id_name');
    $usernameLabel = $('#name_label');
    $email = $('#id_email');
    $emailLabel = $('#email_label');
    $subject = $('#id_subject');
    $subjectLabel = $('#subject_label');
    $message = $('#id_message');
    $messageLabel = $('#message_label');
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/landingFloatingField.js' %}"></script>
```

**landingFloatingField.js**:

```
// Freezes the floating labels above the form fields
$(function() {
    // Save current value of element
    $username.data('oldVal', $username.val());

    $username.bind('properties change click keyup input paste', function(event) {
        // If value has changed...
        if ($username.data('oldVal') !== $username.val()) {
            // Updated stored value
            $username.data('oldVal', $username.val());
            // Add freeze class
            $usernameLabel.addClass('freeze');
            // If the new value has length
            if (!$username.val().length){
                $usernameLabel.removeClass('freeze');
            }
        }
    });
    // Save current value of element
    $email.data('oldVal', $email.val());

    $email.bind('properties change click keyup input paste', function(event) {
        // If value has changed...
        if ($email.data('oldVal') !== $email.val()) {
            // Updated stored value
            $email.data('oldVal', $email.val());
            // Add freeze class
            $emailLabel.addClass('freeze');
            // If the new value has length
            if (!$email.val().length){
                $emailLabel.removeClass('freeze');
            }
        }
    });
...
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="/contact/">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <fieldset class="mb-4">
                        <div class="form-row mt-4">

                            <!-- Name -->
                            <div class="form-group form-field col-md-6">
                                <input type="text"
                                       name="name"
                                       class="textinput textInput form-control"
                                       id="id_name"
                                       value="{% if form.name.value %}{{ form.name.value }}{% endif %}">
                                <label class="form-label {% if form.name.value %}freeze{% endif %}"
                                       for="id_name"
                                       id="name_label">Name</label>
                                {% if form.name.errors %}
                                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                                <p class="text-danger font-weight-bold m-1" id="errors_name">{{ error|escape }}</p>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
```

Comment: Some sample html showing label/input/container structure would help in making this generic

Comment: Updated it to show what the HTML looks like

Comment: Event delegation and `$("#contactForm :input")`

Comment: Okay. I will look it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it generic by starting with a collection of all the form controls you want to apply that logic to and loop over them all to set the initial `oldVal` as well as to add the event listener(s) to each

Then within the event handler `this` is the element event occurred on and you can traverse to the associated label.

The selector `:input` returns all form controls and I excluded checkbox and radios. Modify accordingly

Something like:

```js
const $inputs = $('#contactForm :input').not(':radio,:checkbox')

$inputs.each(function() {
  $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());
})

$inputs.on('properties change click keyup input paste', function(event) {
  const $inp = $(this),
    currVal = $inp.val(),
    $label = $inp.siblings('label')
  // If value has changed...
  if ($inp.data('oldVal') !== currVal) {
    // Updated stored value
    $inp.data('oldVal', currVal);
    // Add freeze class
    $label.addClass('freeze');
    // If the new value has length
    if (!currVal.length) {
      $label.removeClass('freeze');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.freeze {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm">

  <div class="form-group form-field col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_name" value="Foo Bar">
    <label class="form-label " for="id_name" id="name_label">Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-field col-md-6">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_email" value="foo@bar.com">
    <label class="form-label " for="id_email" id="email_label">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-field col-md-6">
    
    <textarea id="id_message">Blah blah blah</textarea>
    <label class="form-label " for="id_message" id="message_label">Message</label>

  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do! Great code for me to study! thanks a bunch for taking the time to show me how!

Comment: Instead of `.addClass('freeze')` and then remove it when the current value is the empty string, you can do this in one step with [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) -> `$label.toggleClass('freeze', currVal.length > 0)`